# how to convert string to integer and compare specify number use mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use sql to get `text` value,and convert `text` string to integer to compare same specify numbers.
Forgive my poor English.
Step 1,I use this sql get `text` value.(The result is Like '8000mAh','2000mAh')

```
SELECT `product_id`, `text` 
FROM `jfw_product_attribute` 
WHERE `attribute_id` =3
```

Step 2,I use sql convert `text` string to integer to compare same specify numbers:(I delete the last three str 'mAh')

```
SELECT `product_id` ,
CASE
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <1000
THEN 1
WHEN 1000 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=2000
THEN 2
WHEN 2001 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=3000
THEN 3
WHEN 3001 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=4000
THEN 4
WHEN 4001 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=5000
THEN 5
WHEN 5001 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=8000
THEN 6
WHEN 8001 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int)
THEN 7
END AS `filter_id`
FROM `jfw_product_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_id` =3
```

I cant get right `filter_id`,I just get all `filter_id` is 2.Someone can help me?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below as the `case` statement will match the first possible filter so all you need to do is to match based on `<=`

```
SELECT `product_id` ,
CASE
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <1000
THEN 1
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=2000
THEN 2
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=3000
THEN 3
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=4000
THEN 4
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=5000
THEN 5
WHEN cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int) <=8000
THEN 6
WHEN 8001 <= cast( REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( text ) , 4 ) ) as  UNSIGNED int)
THEN 7
END AS `filter_id`
FROM `jfw_product_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_id` =3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply cast `text` directly to a number; indeed, using it within a numeric context will do this implicitly.  One could therefore do something like:

```sql
SELECT product_id, text DIV 1000 + 1 AS filter_id
FROM   jfw_product_attribute
WHERE  attribute_id = 3
```

Note however, that this won't yield *exactly* the same results as had been intended by your original `CASE` statement:

- it treats the endpoints differently (i.e. a value equal to 2000 will yield 3 rather than 2); and
- it treats every thousand as a different interval, whereas 5001-8000 and 8001+ were originally aggregated.

That said, it ought to be pretty trivial to achieve what you want by adapting this approach.